# Where can I find the Default settings of <sessionState> element?

Tags: asp.net, iis

file

> c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config

doesn't have this element. Where these options are keeping?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858951/how-do-i-determine-the-following-default-web-config-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default settings for `<sessionSate>` is not explicitly configured in the Machine.config file or in the root Web.config file. The default values are documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and I am quoting it below

> ```
> <sessionState 
>    mode="InProc" 
>    stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
>    stateNetworkTimeout="10" 
>    sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
>    sqlCommandTimeout="30" 
>    customProvider="" 
>    cookieless="UseCookies" 
>    cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" 
>    timeout="20" 
>    allowCustomSqlDatabase="false" 
>    regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
>    partitionResolverType="" 
>    useHostingIdentity="true">
>    <providers>
>       <clear />
>    </providers>
> </sessionState>
> ```

Comment: yes, but where they come from? These settings protection in .dll?

Comment: Yes, these are default values for the configuration section