# error message "Server Too Busy" in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-8.1

Every time when I ran my .net application I get message "Server Too Busy" on web page. After that when I press F5 it works.

I am using Windows8.1 with 64 machine with VS2010.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server Too Busy in vs2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771097/server-too-busy-in-vs2012)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="72000" maxRequestLength="4096" minFreeThreads="72" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="88" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" />
</system.web>
```

Source: http://www.codegain.com/articles/aspnet/miscellaneous/how-to-resolve-the-server-too-busy-error-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: I had no luck with this. It may be because I also installed VS2013.